# Browser redirecting SharePoint URL with ms-word:nft|u|

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, redirect

I have been working with a client's SharePoint document on their network using my Microsoft credentials with no problem. Recently there have been errors and can't access. On all browsers. Noticed last night the URL when clicked redirects to a new URL that has ms-word:nft|u|https appended to the beginning.  Have no idea what's happened and can't find answers on Google searches. Please help!

I have a subscription to Office 365, Windows 7 64-bit. Had previously Office 2007 as well as 365 with no issues for months. But did uninstall 2007 recently hoping having only one Office would work.  I also did an online repair on my Office 365 yesterday to no avail.